# find the highest product you can get from three of the integers in an array - how to solve using brute force

Tags: java, algorithm

```
int arr[] = {10, 10, 1, 3};
```

Assumptions: Assume every int is positive. Assume array contains at least 3 ints

Find the highest product you can get from three of the integers in the above array. We should return 300 (which we get by taking 10 ∗ 10 ∗ 3).

I want to solve this using brute force method. Basically, I want to multiply each integer by each other integer, and then multiply that product by each other other integer.  Can anyone show me how this can be done using nested 3 loops **because I want to learn how it's done using brute force first before trying the optimized approach.**

Thanks.

Comment: Why not sorting the array and using the 3 largest values after sorting?

Comment: What is the possible range? Can any element be negative? Can an element be zero?

Comment: @YCF_L: Will not work well if negatives and zero are allowed. Currently the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I have edited my questions. Hope it makes more sense now

Comment: @MGarp: Thanks for the edit. It's *much* simpler if the `int`s are all positive. Downvote converted to upvote.

Comment: @Anonymous why sort when it can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) extra space?

Comment: Someone should probably just post the brute force solution as an answer to [Find maximum product of 3 numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550037/find-maximum-product-of-3-numbers-in-an-array) and then we can close this as a duplicate and have all the solutions to this problem in one place, because one solution here, a few solutions somewhere else and some more elsewhere doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Side sigh: *"Assume every int is positive"* spoils all the fan: the right question should be "an array with length >= 3 with **arbitrary** int's...". Negative , zero items and integer overflow (when multiplying) will make the problem its charm. And, of course, `O(N)` complexity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using three for loops :

```
public static Integer highestProduct(int array[]) 
{
    if((array==null)||(array.length<3))
    {
        return null;
    }

    else
    {
        int max_product = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=j+1;k<array.length;k++)
                {
                    int product = array[i]*array[j]*array[k];
                    if(product>=max_product)
                    {
                        max_product = product;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return max_product;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Nice analysis, especially the check at the beginning. The indentation could be improved though. I find `int product = 1` more palatable given the other constraints.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I edit it. I also improve the indentation.

Comment: Although cute, the algorithm is faulty in that it suffers from integer overflow.

Comment: Arf, you're right again, i didn't think of that possibility... Maybe with the Math library and Math.BigInteger or long.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: You should exchange `product` and `max_product`.

Comment: Of course, I also reuse Interger.MIN_VALUE just in case the user use negative int.

Comment: return should be max_product I guess.

Comment: Oh my god, sorry guys, I'm really tired!

Comment: It would be clearer what happens at the end with i<length-2 and j<length-1

Comment: @m69 Although just sticking to `i<array.length` is simpler and much less prone to error and (IMO) confusion and the running time either way is roughly the same.

Answer (score 2):

there are some solutions to ignore brute force.

**1. Sort**

First you can sort array, it takes O(nlogn) time. 
After sorting select last 3 items. As they are highest items, then product will maximum

> NOTE: It will not work if there are any negative numbers in your array. 
>   For fixing it you can check some combinations. First calculate first 3 items product, then last 3, then First 2 and Last 1. One of these will be greatest.

**2. Dynamic programming**

Please see [matrix chain multiplication](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/) or [max growing length](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-14-maximum-sum-increasing-subsequence/) problems and dynamic programming solutions for them. It will help you to understand what is dynamic programming and create simple algorithm to solve your problem.